# Serve flask python on https and another port without https

Tags: python, nginx, flask

What I'm trying to accomplish.
Have a domain on https. Check. it's working ok using the following config. The flask app runs on port 1337 -> nginx takes it -> serves it though https. Everything is working nicely

Now I want to run another app, on port 1338 let's say. But if I do this, the browser (chrome) automatically redirects it to https.
I want: http://example.com:1338  .... to run ok
I get: https://example.com:1338 ... error certificate

My question is: how can I make the other app (on port 1338) either work with https:// or to work with http://

Here's my config...

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;


        root /home/cleverbots;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;



        # SSL configuration
        #
        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

        ssl_certificate     /xxxxxxxxxx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /xxxxxxxxxx.key;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
        resolver_timeout 5s;
        # Disable preloading HSTS for now.  You can use the commented out header line that includes
        # the "preload" directive if you understand the implications.
        #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

        ssl_dhparam /xxxxxx/dhparam.pem;




        location /static/ {
               expires 30d;
               add_header Last-Modified $sent_http_Expires;
               alias /home/my_first_app/application/static/;
        }


        location / {
                try_files $uri @tornado;
        }

        location @tornado {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:1337;
        }



}
```

Comment: If you want this app to be accessible to the public via a browser, then you'll need to add a subdomain for it listening on 80 port. If you're just using it for API calls (say), then you can create a new server block on a custom port and then have Nginx proxy it to port 1338

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on what exactly you want the user experience to be.

As I understand your goal, you only have one domain (example.com). Your first app, (I'm going to call it `app1337`) is running on port 1337 and you can access in a browser at https://example.com/. Now you want to add another app (`app1338`) that you want to be able to access at https://example.com:1338/. The problem here is that only one service can run on a given port on a given interface. This can work, but means that you have to be really careful to make sure that your flask app *only* listens on loopback (127.0.0.1) and Nginx only listens on your Ethernet interface. If not, you'll get "socket already in use" errors. I would recommend instead using something else like 8338 in Nginx to avoid this confusion.

The fastest solution I can see would be to leave your existing server block exactly as is. Duplicate the entire thing, and in the new block:

1. Change the 2 `listen 443` lines to the port you want to use in browser
   (8338).
2. Remove the `listen 80` lines or, if you want to serve the app on both ssl and non-ssl,  change the port to the non-ssl port you want to use.
3. Change your `proxy_pass` line to point to your second flask app.

Like Keenan, I would recommend you use subdomains to sort your traffic. Something like https://app1337.example.com/ and https://app1338.example.com/ to make for a better user experience. To do this, duplicate the server block as above, but this time leave the ports the same, but change the "server_name" directive in each block to match the domain. Remove all of the "default_server" parts from the listen directives.

As an example:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name app1337.example.com;

        # SSL configuration 
        # Certificate and key for "app1337.example.com"
        ssl_certificate     /xxxxxxxxxx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /xxxxxxxxxx.key;

        # The rest of the ssl stuff is common and can be moved to a shared file and included
        # in whatever blocks it is needed.
        include sslcommon.conf;

        root /home/cleverbots;
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location /static/ {
               expires 30d;
               add_header Last-Modified $sent_http_Expires;
               alias /home/my_first_app/application/static/;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri @tornado;
        }

        location @tornado {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:1337;
        }
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name app1338.example.com;

        # SSL configuration 
        # Certificate and key for "app1338.example.com"
        ssl_certificate     /xxxxxxxxxx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /xxxxxxxxxx.key;

        # The rest of the ssl stuff is common and can be moved to a shared file and included
        # in whatever blocks it is needed.
        include sslcommon.conf;

        ## This might be different for app1338
        root /home/cleverbots;
        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        ## This might be different for app1338
        location /static/ {
               expires 30d;
               add_header Last-Modified $sent_http_Expires;
               alias /home/my_first_app/application/static/;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri @app1338;
        }

        location @app1338 {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:1338;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I also must add that for sockets you have to add         proxy_pass http://localhost:1338;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection “upgrade”;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;